# what is the terminology or idiom for using an object of the class to get a reference to its contents?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, static, idioms

A [previously question on static references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14932169/262852) was closed as vague.  In any event, I now know the the answer (and will hopefully remember the "solution"), but what is this technique called?

The most popular answer states:

> Your instance variable cannot be referenced from a static context. You
>   need an object of the class to get (a reference to) it's contents.

This question has been asked before.  Surely there's a catch-phrase for this approach?

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: It's more of a "fact" than an "approach".

Comment: It simply is the difference between an instance and a class variable. A class variable belongs to the class (is static) whereas an instance variable needs an instance...

Comment: it's a non-standard main method, so I thought it might have a name for this "fact".

Comment: The `main` method is an entry point - it should create instances of objects and pass on processing to them. Java is a OO language not a scripting language...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you have a class that doesn't look like it needs any `static` members, but you are trying to work in a static context because a `static main` method gets Dr.Frankensteined onto the class.

Don't do that. Just put `main` on another class instead. The accepted answer to that other question is good for a quick and dirty solution, but it's quite dirty.

Comment: It's just something I've seen my instructor do, arguing that the class is reusable because the methods and fields aren't static; also some Swing generated classes do this.

Comment: The class is reusable in the same sense that a car with a sofa strapped on top is perfectly usable for road travel. That still doesn't mean you should design a factory model that way.

Comment: LOL.  Ok, just confirming much of the "advice" that my instructor gives is suspect.